# Having trouble refactoring Submit Index class that extends deprecated Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

Tags: magento2, controllers

```
<?php

namespace Alex\AskQuestion\Controller\Submit;

use Alex\AskQuestion\Model\AskQuestionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Index extends Action
{
    public const STATUS_ERROR = 'Error';

    public const STATUS_SUCCESS = 'Success';

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private Validator $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var AskQuestionFactory
     */
    private $askQuestionFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor
     *
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param AskQuestionFactory $askQuestionFactory
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Validator          $formKeyValidator,
        AskQuestionFactory $askQuestionFactory,
        Context            $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->askQuestionFactory = $askQuestionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        try {

            if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($request) || $request->getParam('hideit')) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Something went wrong.
                Probably you were away for quite a long time already.
                Please, reload the page and try again.'));
            }

            if (!$request->isAjax()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('This request is not valid and can not be processed.'));
            }

            $askQuestion = $this->askQuestionFactory->create();
            $askQuestion->setName($request->getParam('name'))
                ->setEmail($request->getParam('email'))
                ->setPhone($request->getParam('phone'))
                ->setProductName($request->getParam('product_name'))
                ->setSku($request->getParam('sku'))
                ->setQuestion($request->getParam('question'));
            $askQuestion->save();

            $data = [
                'status' => self::STATUS_SUCCESS,
                'message' => __('Your request was submitted. We\'ll get in touch with you as soon as possible.')
            ];

        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $data = [
                'status' => self::STATUS_ERROR,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @var Json $controllerResult
         */
        $controllerResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);

        return $controllerResult->setData($data);
    }
}
```

What is the correct implementation of ActionInterface in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the POST method is used for the form submit controller. Therefore, you only need to implement the `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface`. Moreover, there is no longer a need to extend the `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` abstract class. This change is a result of the "**Decomposition of Magento Controllers**" and has made the abstract **Action** class deprecated.

Your class should be structured as follows.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Alex\AskQuestion\Controller\Submit;

use Alex\AskQuestion\Model\AskQuestionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Index implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    public const STATUS_ERROR = 'Error';

    public const STATUS_SUCCESS = 'Success';

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private Validator $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var AskQuestionFactory
     */
    private $askQuestionFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor
     *
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param AskQuestionFactory $askQuestionFactory
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Validator $formKeyValidator,
        AskQuestionFactory $askQuestionFactory
    ) {
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->askQuestionFactory = $askQuestionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //...your code goes here
    }
}
```

> If you want to explicitly define what methods are going to be handled
> by the Controller, the most common interfaces are: `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpDeleteActionInterface \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPutActionInterface`
>
> Please be aware that the `HEAD` method is handled the same way that `GET` is.

Read more about **Decomposition of Magento Controller** at https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Decomposition-of-Magento-Controllers/ba-p/430883